# Can not add bibtex reference

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I am new to latex and I have a problem in refrencing other papers in my work, I downloade the latex template from here:

[get template](http://thesai.org/Home/Downloads)

Also I want to for example cite this paper:
[a paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1772751)

so for example I copied the bibtex from this website and copy it in the bibography section so I have:[image]

But nothing happens I really do not know how to add it then can anyone help?

Comment: The site's paper_format.tex has a single bibliography entry in it. If you modify that bibliography entry and rebuild the document, does the PDF update accordingly?

Comment: I think the problem rather lies with OP inserting a BibTeX object inside LaTeX's `thebibliography` environment. OP, if you're going to use BibTeX (the @inproceedings/etc. stuff), I'm pretty sure you need to use it for every reference. Otherwise, you should format your citation manually.

Comment: Yep. The @ alone would kill it. Should have noticed that.

Comment: [My answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256405/) may help a little. [The question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256403/question-about-bibitem-book-and-bibtex-and-how-to-use-calibre-to-make-a-bibte) concerns a similar kind of 'mismatch' involving distinct ways to create a bibliography.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Well, it is much more difficult to read screen shots of code than to read code which has been pasted and properly formatted, as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're encountering arises because you are mixing-and-(mis)matching two different methods for creating a bibliography. First, the template you're using (from `http://thesai.org/Home/Downloads/`) provides the following, already-compiled `thebibliography` environment:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{IEEEhowto:kopka}
H.~Kopka and P.~W. Daly, \emph{A Guide to \LaTeX}, 3rd~ed.\hskip 1em plus
  0.5em minus 0.4em\relax Harlow, England: Addison-Wesley, 1999.

\end{thebibliography}
```

(The blank lines are essential, by the way, for LaTeX to be able to compile this part correctly.) Second, you've found the following, BibTeX-formatted entry online:

```
@inproceedings{Kwak:2010:TSN:1772690.1772751,
 author = {Kwak, Haewoon and Lee, Changhyun and Park, Hosung and Moon, Sue},
 title = {What is Twitter, a Social Network or a News Media?},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the 19th International Conference on World Wide Web},
 series = {WWW '10},
 year = {2010},
 isbn = {978-1-60558-799-8},
 location = {Raleigh, North Carolina, USA},
 pages = {591--600},
 numpages = {10},
 url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1772690.1772751},
 doi = {10.1145/1772690.1772751},
 acmid = {1772751},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
 keywords = {Twitter, degree of separation, homophily, influential, information diffusion, online social network, pagerank, reciprocity, retweet},
}
```

As you've discovered, simply dumping this entry into the existing `thebibliography` environment does not work.

Assuming you don't need to reference the Kopka and Daly book, and assuming further that you don't want to format by hand the Kwak et al piece, here's what you need to do:

- Replace the entire existing `thebibliography` environment with a single statement:

  ```
  \bibliography{myreferences}
  ```
- Create a new file called `myreferences.bib` (the extension `bib` is essential), and place the BibTeX-formatted entry shown above in that file. All further bibtex-style entries should also be placed in this file. Save the bib file in the directory where your main tex file is located.
- Back in your main tex file, be sure to have one or more `\cite{Kwak:2010:TSN:1772690.1772751}` instructions in the appropriate locations. Note the string "`Kwak:2010:TSN:1772690.1772751`" -- it's the very first string of the entry you placed in the file `references.bib`. The string is called the "key" to the corresponding entry.
- Run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

By the end of this, there should a citation call-out in the body of the document as well as a correctly formatted bibliography.

---

Here's the screenshot of the result of assembling these instructions. The example code uses the `filecontents` package to make the code self-contained and compilable. In practice, you should have separate `.tex` and `.bib` files.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}  
\begin{filecontents}{myreferences.bib}
@inproceedings{Kwak:2010:TSN:1772690.1772751,
 author = {Kwak, Haewoon and Lee, Changhyun and Park, Hosung and Moon, Sue},
 title = {What is Twitter, a Social Network or a News Media?},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the 19th International Conference on World Wide Web},
 series = {WWW '10},
 year = {2010},
 isbn = {978-1-60558-799-8},
 location = {Raleigh, North Carolina, USA},
 pages = {591--600},
 numpages = {10},
 url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1772690.1772751},
 doi = {10.1145/1772690.1772751},
 acmid = {1772751},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
 keywords = {Twitter, degree of separation, homophily, influential, information diffusion, online social network, pagerank, reciprocity, retweet},
} 
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[conference, letterpaper]{IEEEtran}
%% the following preamble is a compressed version of the template's material
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
   \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\else
\fi
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\thispagestyle}[2]{} 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
        \fancyhead{}
        \fancyhead[C]{first page center header}
        \fancyfoot{}
        \fancyfoot[C]{first page center footer}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight 20pt
\footskip 20pt
\rhead{}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\fancyhead[R]{\textit{(IJACSA) International Journal of Advanced Computer Science and Applications, \\ Vol. XXX, No. XXX, 3001}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{www.ijacsa.thesai.org}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage \  $|$ P a g e }

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\cite{Kwak:2010:TSN:1772690.1772751}

\bibliography{myreferences}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I followed what u said and I created bib file the I added \bibliography{myreferences} in tex file and I used this line somewhere in the body of text: \cite{Kwak:2010:TSN:1772690.1772751} but I get ? which means unknown in the place of citation and also I get nothing in bibliography

Comment: @HamedMinaee - Which error messages, if any, do you get? Incidentally, did you (a) place the bib file in the same directory as the main tex file, (b) provide a `\bibliographystyle` directive, and (c) run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes?

Comment: No I do no get any error, I just put the file in the same directory should I not do that?

Comment: also what do u mean by providing bibliography ? do u mean this: \bibliography{myreferences} or the content of refrence file?

Comment: Also I am using winedt and I just use compiled buttom 3 times is it enough for compilation or am I missing something?

Comment: @HamedMinaee - Please study the [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001)
 I provided. It (i) creates an external file called "myreferences.bib", (ii) contains the instruction `\bibliography{myreferences}`, and (iii) contains the instruction `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`. Note that `\bibliography` and `\bibliographystyle` are *two separate and distinct instructions*. That's why I asked if your tex file contains a `\bibliographystyle` directive. If this directive is missing, BibTeX won't know what it's supposed to do and, in consequence, do nothing at all.

Comment: @HamedMinaee - A separate issue: Within WinEdt, which "button" do you click on in order to initiate compilation? I suggest you choose the "button" called "PDFTeXify". With this choice in place, WinEdt will automatically run pdfLaTeX and BibTeX as many times as is necessary to resolve all cross-references, including all `cite` instructions.

Comment: U areeeeeeeeeeeeeee awesome worked :)